# Error 403 apache on localhost since update to high sierra

Tags: laravel, macos, apache, localhost

I have a problem since I update macOS X to high sierra version I have some problem running apache service . When I try to access to this url http://social.demo in local I have Forbidden Page 
social.demo is a project made with Laravel

When run this command :

```
apachectl configtest
```

It return me this error :

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Alexiss-iMac.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK
```

So I check in /ect/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1 api.demo
127.0.0.1 tv.demo
127.0.0.1 bo.demo
127.0.0.1 social.demo
127.0.0.1 website.demo
127.0.0.1 revive.demo
127.0.0.1 bo.demo
~
```

It seems ok 
I try to uncomment this in this file "/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf" and restart apache service

```
#Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf
```

Even I try http://localhost I have a forbidden page

I don't where I have to look for ...

Edit : here my httpd-vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/Users/alexisjqn//Documents/Ctor/public/"
ServerName http://social.demo/
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
     <Directory "/Users/alexisjqn//Documents/Ctor/public/">
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Not sure but you may check the file/directory permissions.

Comment: @ab_ab I put  /Library/WebServer/Documents/index.html.en in 777 with a chown root but same problem ...

Comment: I mean the [Directory Permissions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6#configuration) of `storage` and the `bootstrap/cache`.

Comment: @ab_ab 
drwxrwxrwx   6 alexisjqn  staff
for both folders

Comment: The permission issue was my random guess. I don't have much knowledge in this. have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/file-permissions-for-laravel-5-and-others). It might help you.

Answer (score 0):

My Work around was thew following:

1. Please check "/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf" file. Change

   ```
   #Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf
   ```

   to

   ```
   Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf
   ```
2. And edit your "/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"

   change

   ```
   Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
   ```

   to

   ```
   Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews Indexes
   ```

   finally your doc root will be look like the following,

   ```
   DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
   <Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
   Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews Indexes
   MultiviewsMatch Any
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
   ```
3. Restart apache

   ```
   sudo apachectl restart
   ```